# Filtering dataframe based on streamlit date_input

Tags: python, streamlit

I trying to filtering my dataframe based on the streamlit date_input() function `st.date_input()`.
My column CREATEDDATE is on the datetime format :

```
df = ld.load_data_projet()

start_date = st.date_input('Date de début :')
end_date = st.date_input('Date de fin :')
if start_date < end_date:
    pass
else:
    st.error('Error: Date de fin doit être choisi après la dete de début.')

mask = (df['CREATEDDATE'] > start_date) & (df['CREATEDDATE'] <= end_date)
df = df.loc[mask]
# And display the result!
st.dataframe(df)
```

The result showed me this error message :

[image]

Have you any idea of the cause of the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date column like that :

```
df['CREATEDDATE']= pd.to_datetime(df['CREATEDDATE']).dt.date
```

In the end the code show this :

```
start_date, end_date = st.date_input('Choisir date de début, date de fin :', [])
if start_date < end_date:
    pass
else:
    st.error('Error: Date de fin doit être choisi après la dete de début.')

#greater than the start date and smaller than the end date
mask = (df['CREATEDDATE'] > start_date) & (df['CREATEDDATE'] <= end_date)
df = df.loc[mask]
# And display the result!
st.dataframe(df)
```